# SSAS aggregates measure that is set to not aggregate

Tags: sql-server, ssas, cube

I have non-additive measure in my fact table.  I set the measure property AggregateFunction to None:

[image: aggregatefunction]

I processed the cube, and then went to the Browser.  I re-connected to verify I was working with the latest changes in the cube.  But the measure is aggregating.

[image: browser]

How do I keep SSAS from aggregating a non-additive measure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that only the Enterprise version of SQL supports those non-additive measure settings.  So the settings are there, visible and appear to be available, but they don't work.  And there's no error.  Nice "feature", Microsoft.

From [this book](https://books.google.com/books?id=qZlCAwAAQBAJ&lpg=PT291&ots=Yv5J4mzcs7&dq=ssas%20semi-additive%20measure%20aggregation%20types%20enterprise&pg=PT291#v=onepage&q=ssas%20semi-additive%20measure%20aggregation%20types%20enterprise&f=false):

> Also semi-additive measures require Enterpise edition of SSAS

And from [this blog](http://www.purplefrogsystems.com/blog/2008/04/semi-additive-measures-using-sql-server-standard/):

> One of the most frustrating limitations of SQL Server 2005 Standard
>   edition is that it doesn’t support semi additive measures in SSAS
>   Analysis Services cubes